# Monitor User launch Accessibility Settings of specific downloaded app Android

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I'm a new Android developer. I'm developing a parental control app, and after referring a few existing apps like Qustodio, i discovered that when users open the accessibility settings, a login pop-up appears right away.

I attempted to use the accessibility service but didn't work.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.